# Does falling count as movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, falling

I'm planning to play a Sun Soul Aarakocra monk. With the flight of the Aarakocra I can essentially hit someone, fly up and repeat. Let's say I fly up 50 feet and decide to drop to the ground. Does the 50 feet drop count against my movement or no? Is there any rules that specify that so I can justify it to my DM.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. [Does this question match yours](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121584/does-deliberately-falling-cost-movement)? If not, please edit the question to clarify what makes it unique.